# how to make a static struct from typedef

Tags: c, struct, static

I have a header file list.h and a source file list.c,which define the functions in list.h.
I have a struct here:

```
    typedef struct ListNode{
 struct ListNode* next;
 struct ListNode* prev;
 void *value;
    }Node;
    typedef struct List{
 Node *first;
 Node *last;
 int count;
    }List;
```

How can i make them only visible to the functions in list.h,when the compiler does not accept using static and typedef together? These are the functions i declare in list.h:

```
    List *List_create();
    void List_destroy(List *list);
    void *List_remove(List *list,Node *node);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you wish the struct types to be visible only in `list.c`, or are you trying to declare static variables of those types?

Comment: Use the static when you declare the variable, not in the `typedef`.

Comment: yes i want the struct types to be only visible in list.c.

Comment: i have edited it, sorry i pasted my code without checking.

Comment: @ThomasJager i did try it, but the compiler throws an error "expected specifier-qualifier-list before static". Somebody in this site also mentioned that you cannot declare static variable inside a struct.

Comment: @VanTeoLe If you only want the types visible in list.c, then put the typedefs in list.c.

Comment: When you say you want the struct types to be invisible, do you mean that only the pointer types `Node *` and `List *` are to be exposed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers to opaque structs to hide the contents of your structs `List` and `Node`. In the header, use include only the opaque declarations

```
typedef struct ListNode Node;
typedef struct List List;
```

and the function declarations. These tell the compiler that the structs and typedefs exist, but not what the structs contain.

In `list.c`, include the full declarations, but not as typedefs, since the header file already tells the compiler about the typedef'ed names.

```
struct ListNode {
    /* contents */
};
struct List {
    /* contents */
};
```

This way the contents of the structs are not usable in other C files, but the functions in `list.c` can still use them. This also means that other C files cannot create new instances of these structs, except by using the functions offered in `list.h`.

Comment: how should i declare it in list.c? Like typedef struct ListNode {element..} Node?